# Prolog getting the maximum out of a collection

Tags: prolog

This is a simple question.

```
has(steve, 5).
has(mark, 6).
has(craig, 4).
```

How do you get who has the most from this in Prolog?

I have tried `has(Who, Max)` but that doesn't help. Is there an operator that can be used here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```erlang
?- has(U,S),\+((has(V,T),T>S)).
U = mark,
S = 6 ;
false.
```

The prefix operator `\+` read as **not**. Since what we must disprove is a conjunction, expressed by the infix operator `,`, those double parenthesis are required.

You should be aware, when using it, that it is a *restricted* form of negation, so called [negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure), made possible by the [closed world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption) that is implicit in Prolog semantics.

## Alternatively, doing exactly the same

```
max(U,S) :- has(U,S),notanybetterthan(S).

notanybetterthan(S) :- has(_,T),T>S,!,fail.
notanybetterthan(_).
```

or

```
max(U,S) :- has(U,S),\+anybetterthan(S).

anybetterthan(S) :- has(_,T),T>S.
```

*edit*

As noted by @WillNess, the syntax I used was imprecise. Indeed the double parenthesis are a consequece of `\+` seen as a *functor*, not as *operator*. Adding a space after the symbol we can write instead

```
?- has(U,S),\+ (has(V,T),T>S).
```

Comment: Most idiomatic solution. Where `\+` is to be read as "notfindany".

Comment: What did you run this using? It failed on Strawberry Prolog.

Comment: Note that this also works naturally, returning multiple solutions, if there is `has(ellie,6)`. I will allow myself to add "Alternative"

Comment: `has(U,S),\+ (has(V,T),T>S).` also works, can't be mistaken for a (binary) predicate invocation (NB the space after the `\+`).

Comment: @WillNess: thanks, was missing that detail. Will edit the answer to include your note.

Comment: @CapelliC - Strawberry didn't like `\+`. It was, however, happy with `not(...)`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer personally, I prefer "can't prove ...". here we have `∃ U,S. has(U,S) Λ ¬(∃ T. has(_,T) Λ T>S)` i.e. `∃ U,S. has(U,S) Λ (∀ T. has(_,T) ⇒ ¬(T>S))` : "there does not exist, as far as we know, ..." i.e. "we cannot prove that there exists ...".

Comment: @CapelliC I learned this from @ false's comment once, IIRC. was always using double parens till then. :) Of course nowadays I love me an extra white space everywhere I can add it, anyway.

Comment: In the old days, a good numbers of Prolog systems had buggy `write_canonical/1-2` predicates that would omit the space resulting in that error when reading back the code.

Comment: @CapelliC you also wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352422/849891) once, with `aggregate`-based solution, to complement [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351511/849891) which had both `not`- and `findall`- based code in it, and a good complexity discussion. Even the space after the `\+` operator was discussed there in the comments. :)

Comment: @WillNess For me it's `\+`== "there is no evidence for..." in general.

Comment: Those double parentheses behave weirdly! `write_canonical(\+(has(V,T),T>S)).` -->
`\+(has(_,A),>(A,_))`.  But double parantheses, adding a space after `\+` or both always bring: ` \+(','(has(_,A),>(A,_)))` ... a conjunction with an empty element!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard predicates `findall/3` and `keysort/2`:

```
| ?- findall(Value-Name, has(Name, Value), Pairs),
     keysort(Pairs, SortedPairs).

Pairs = [5-steve, 6-mark, 4-craig],
SortedPairs = [4-craig, 5-steve, 6-mark]
yes
```

You want the last pair in the `SortedPairs` list. Simply walk the list until you reach its last element. I will leave that to you to write a `last(List, Last)` predicate.

**Update**

Carlo's solution is nicely idiomatic (+1). But it's also O(n^2). My solution (including the missing `last/2` predicate) is O(2*n + n*log(n)). On the other hand, it hits the garbage collector slightly more due to the temporary lists that are created. If we have only the tree facts in the OP, Carlo's solution is ~3x faster. With ~100 facts, both solutions take roughly the same amount of time (note that exact numbers depend on the used Prolog system). For a large number of facts, the differences in complexity become more and more apparent.

Comment: right, except, there could be more than one `Name`s with the same maximal `Value`. which can also be dealt with in *O(n)* overall (on top the *n log n* sort of course), but the plot thickens (the code complexity explodeth). Prolog is supposed to be declarative magic! (which it of course is not :) (but maybe it could) ). the difference is that the `not`-based code could potentially produce its first answer after *O(n)* steps, but the list-based does more work upfront, so, can't. Interestingly, a *lazy* language will *always* produce its first answer in *O(n)*, with the list-based approach...

Comment: ... and the answer by @Enigmativity produces its result in *O(n)*, always (even if there is more than one, and it's amended to handle this). going the usual way from the most abstract code to the most hand-tailored.

Comment: @WillNess The call to `findall/3` (in both mine and @Enigmativity solutions) is O(n). But then @Enigmativity  solution walks the list making the solution O(2*n). But is solution is also not tail-recursive, which gives a penalty w.r.t. space complexity. With a change to use an accumulator to make it tail-recursive, it should be faster than the other solutions.

Comment: so looks like the "ultimate" solution is to reimplement/specialize `findall/3` itself and tweak it to find only the maximal elements instead. doing all the extra-logical assertions/retractions in the failure-driven loop ourselves; i.e. the most *manual* coding. can't really a system exist (already) that would go into the trenches and do this *for* us on its own, so we can stick with the highest-level declarative coding styles?....

Comment: @WillNess Not sure. It may be possible (depending on the underlying application) to simply hold the data in a heap data structure. Logtalk supports both max and min heaps (https://logtalk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries/heaps.html) and will run in most Prolog systems. This would provide a O(1) solution.

Comment: btw [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349912/prolog-find-minimum-value-query) a near-duplicate from 7 years ago. :) same complexity discussion in one answer, and a solution with library(aggregate) from @CapelliC in another.  so turns out what I suggested already exists. :)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go:

```
has(steve, 5).
has(mark, 6).
has(craig, 4).

?- findall(has(X, Y), has(X, Y), Z), maxhas(Z, has(Who, Max)), write([Who, Max]).

maxhas([has(X, Y)], has(X, Y)).
maxhas([has(_, Y)|Hs], has(A, B)) :- maxhas(Hs, has(A, B)), B >= Y.
maxhas([has(X, Y)|Hs], has(X, Y)) :- maxhas(Hs, has(_, B)), B < Y.
```

I get:

```
[mark, 6]Yes.
```

Comment: your code has the lowest complexity, *O(n)*. [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112262/prolog-getting-the-maximum-out-of-a-collection#comment108136381_61114407).